# Unbind a jQuery Plugin?

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I have a plugin like

`$.fn.mycoolplugin`

which binds `mousemove` to the document like

```
$(document).("mousemove", function() {
    //bunch of stuff
});
```

after you call the function on a selector

`$('.myclass').mycoolplugin();`

How would I unbind this because the `mousemove` is bound to the document and OTHER stuff in my code uses `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` ?

Comment: Generally standard jQuery plugins have a destroy method so you can call $('.myclass').mycoolplugin('destroy').  You may want to add that in.  There is an example of this in the jQuery authoring docs.

Comment: You gotta remember all the elements bound to the event and call unbind each.

Comment: @john - yeah I tried to contact the author - but alas no response :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unbind any handler by calling `.unbind`:

```
$(document).unbind("mousemove");
```

This will unbind all `mousemove` handlers from `document`. Do note that doing this might break the plugin's functionality (with the risk of breaking any other code/plugin that adds `mousemove` handler to `document`).

Comment: thanks :) yeah I tried that - the problem is that unbinds all events on the document which causes issues with other sections of my code that use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` ?

Comment: It'll only unbind `mousemove`, and not `mouseleave`/`mouseenter`

Comment: yeah I also use `mousemove` on another part :D Nightmare really :/

Comment: Then use namespaced events in your code: `$(document).bind("mousemove.myCode");`. and unbind the namespaced event only.

Comment: yep, I'll use namespaces as you've suggested :) Will make it much simpler consider plugin doesn't have `destroy`. Thanks!

Comment: btw - can you unbind a function like `$(document).unbind('mousemove', myfunction(event_data));`

Answer (score 0):

You would change how your plugin binds and then releases it's attached handlers like so:

1. You make a function that is responsible for binding all your initial events (such as the mousemover, etc)
2. You make a function that is responsible for unbinding all your initial events.
3. When you bind to an event, do not use an anoymous function. Instead, define a specific handler for the event. That way, when you attach, you do so like so:

   $(document).bind('mousemove', myFuncDelegate);

And then when you need to remove it from scope, you unbind:

```
 $(document).unbind('mousemove', myFuncDelegate);
```

That way you only unattach your events. See http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ for details.

Simply call your bind method on load, and when you decide to unload it, call the unbind method.

Comment: Another way to do it is to give your mousemove a "namespace" -> $(document).bind('mousemove.myNs', function() { }); and then $(document).unbind('mousemove.myNs');